# how to select with where clause in same table but the string that get pass to table is in a same textbox but has different id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

guy's i want to ask about selecting with where clause.
the where clause i use `$kode=$_POST['kode_mat']` and i call it in sql query into `kode='$kode'`. 
nah the problem is.. when i have a string that need to pass into the sql query is same, like i use `$kode` but the `$_POST['kode_mat']` has different id like `kode_mat1,kode_mat2,kode_mat3,kode_mat4,kode_mat5`. and i want to pass it into sql query `$sql ="SELECT * FROM material WHERE kode='$kode' ";`. how to do it?

i have try to separate the php function into 5 php file. and i think that's make my directory has many file that has been saved. i use this code for the 5 php file

```html
<?php
include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");

$kode=$_POST['kode_mat']; // the variable for pass string i just change $_POST['']; ['kode_mat1'],['kode_mat2'],['kode_mat3']....

// Data for Titik1
$sql ="SELECT * FROM material WHERE kode='$kode' "; // and the query still same just change the id's of the textbox that i need to pass the string

$query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$rows = array();

while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $tmp;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

this code above has no problem. it show the right value that i need. but i want to try it to make my separate php fuction can be called as one php. 
i has to try two code like this but it not work.

1st code i have try

```html
<?php
include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");

$kode=$_POST['kode_mat'];
$kode=$_POST['kode_mat1'];
$kode=$_POST['kode_mat2'];
$kode=$_POST['kode_mat3'];
$kode=$_POST['kode_mat4'];
$kode=$_POST['kode_mat5'];
// Data for Titik1
$sql ="SELECT * FROM material WHERE kode='$kode' ";
$query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$rows = array();

while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $tmp;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

and the second code i have try

```html
<?php
include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");

$kode=$_POST['kode_mat'];
$kode1=$_POST['kode_mat1'];
$kode2=$_POST['kode_mat2'];
$kode3=$_POST['kode_mat3'];
$kode4=$_POST['kode_mat4'];
$kode5=$_POST['kode_mat5'];
// Data for Titik1
$sql ="SELECT * FROM material WHERE kode='$kode' OR kode='$kode1' OR kode='$kode2' OR kode='$kode3' OR kode='$kode4' OR kode='$kode5'";
$query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$rows = array();

while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $tmp;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to separate out `$_POST['kode_mat']` into multiple different variables? If you're trying to create a separate function, you could just wrap it in a `function() {}`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge i want to select my data from `table` material. the select method i use jquery on change function from `kode_mat` and the string that need to pass into the `$_POST['']` has different id's. when i make 6 php file just for calling that data i think that's not efficient. nah because of it i want to make that in one file php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use if and else condition here for your solution like below.

```
<?php
include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");

if(isset($_POST['kode_mat']) && $_POST['kode_mat'] != "") {
$kode=$_POST['kode_mat'];
} else if(isset($_POST['kode_mat1']) && $_POST['kode_mat] != "") {
$kode=$_POST['kode_mat1'];
} else if(isset($_POST['kode_mat2']) && $_POST['kode_mat2'] != "") {
$kode=$_POST['kode_mat2'];
} else if(isset($_POST['kode_mat3']) && $_POST['kode_mat3'] != "") {
$kode=$_POST['kode_mat3'];
} else if(isset($_POST['kode_mat4']) && $_POST['kode_mat4'] != "") {
$kode4=$_POST['kode_mat4'];
} else {
$kode=$_POST['kode_mat5'];
}
// Data for Titik1
$sql ="SELECT * FROM material WHERE kode='$kode' ";
$query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$rows = array();

while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $tmp;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: thx so much bro.. your solution work for me.
btw for get data from S_POST we can use if else method for make a condition of the string value that we get. i'm just asking. "When we use If Else function for make a condition like your code. is it make a different  delay of the value from database that got selected? or it not get a different delay?"

Comment: @MinervazMine welcome :) Yes, You can use same method when get from database but at that time don't use isset condition just check with not equal to blank.

Comment: @Jalpha Thx for your suggest